# Separating string values in a text document in to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a text file with 6000 lines . Each line consist of bunch  character which represent different  columns.
Example:
**'AS202003402092020MF1003 EXESTBOPF      01163500116000 000120200381R000540000116000WC05 Watawala Tea Ceylon Ltd.                          1M'**

Above expression is the string and need to extract each column separately as follow:

```
Borkername = AS
Sale year = 2020
Saleno = 0340
sale_dte = 20/9/2020 # date need to be format
Factoryno = MF1003
Catalogu code= EXEST
Grade =BOPF
Gross weight =01163.50 #decimal point needed
Net Weight = 01160.50 #decimal point needed
Lot_No = 0001
invoice_year = 2020
invoice_no = WC05
price = 000540.00 #decimal point needed
Netweight = 01160.00 #decimal point needed
Buyer = 'Watawala Tea Ceylon Ltd.'
Buyer_code = '1M'
```

I have written a code with regular expression to separate each field to column of ***panda data frame*** in python.

```
import re            
import csv
### headings of the dataframe

headings = [
"Borkername", "Sale year", "Saleno", "sale_dte", "Factoryno", "Catalogu code", "Grade", "Gross 
 weight",  "Net Weight", "Lot_No", "invoice_year", "invoice_no", "price", "Netweight", "Buyer", "Buyer_code"]

re_fields = re.compile(r'(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})(.{8})(.{6})(.{5})(.{4})(.{7})(.{7}) (.{4})(.{4})(.{5})(.{8})(.{7}).(.*?) (.{2})$')

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output)
  csv_writer.writerow(headings)

 for line in f_input:
    fields = list(re_fields.match(line).groups())

    fields[3] = "{}.{}.{}".format(fields[3][:2], fields[3][2:4], fields[3][4:])
    fields[7] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[7][:5], fields[7][5:]))
    fields[8] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[8][:5], fields[8][5:]))
    fields[12] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[12][:6], fields[12][6:]))
    fields[13] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[13][:5], fields[13][5:]))

    csv_writer.writerow(fields)
```

Unfortunately this code give error when it try come

```
fields = list(re_fields.match(line).groups())
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Hope that Tech experts may suggest me to do this in proper way, while removing the existing  bug
sample of text file is attached

```
AS202003402092020MF1003 EXESTBOPF      01163500116000 000120200381R000540000116000WC05 Watawala Tea 
Ceylon Ltd.                          1M
AS202003402092020MF0663 EXESTBOPF      01123500112000 000420200165R000550000112000WC05 Watawala Tea 
Ceylon Ltd.                          1M
AS202003402092020MF0069 EXESTBOP       00963500096000 000520200278R000570000096000CM01 Ceylon Tea 
Marketing Ltd.                         1M
AS202003402092020MF0069 EXESTBOPF      01103500110000 000620200282R000580000110000CM01 Ceylon Tea 
Marketing Ltd.                         1M
AS202003402092020MF0348 EXESTBOPF      01163500116000 000720200259R000570000116000CM01 Ceylon Tea 
Marketing Ltd.                         1M
AS202003402092020MF0348 EXESTBOPF      01163500116000 000820200264R000560000116000TT01 Tea Tang (Pvt) 
Ltd                                0M
AS202003402092020MF0703 EXESTBOPF      01123500112000 000920200193R000540000112000AB01 Akbar Brothers 
(Pvt) Ltd                          1M
AS202003402092020MF0552 EXESTBOPF      01123500112000 001120200266 000520000112000AB01 Akbar Brothers 
(Pvt) Ltd                          1M
AS202003402092020MF0294 EXESTBOP       01003500100000 001220200097R000560000100000UL01 Unilever 
Lipton Ceylon Ltd, Tea Division          1M
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not suitable for your input string.

When your code tries to match, it is returned None. In other words, your string is not able to fit your pattern.

I am not an regex expert, but ,with your sample data, this pattern has worked:

```
r'(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})(.{8})(.{6})(\s*.{5})(.{4})(\s*.{7})(.{7})(\s*.{4})(.{4})(\s*.{5})(.{8})(.{7})(.{4})(.*?)(.{2})$'
```

I have also changed the way you split your string to format and include decimal points. Please, check if this works for you:

```
import re            
import csv
### headings of the dataframe

headings = [
"Borkername", "Sale year", "Saleno", "sale_dte", "Factoryno", "Catalogu code", "Grade", "Gross weight",  "Net Weight", "Lot_No", "invoice_year", "invoice_no", "price", "Netweight", "Buyer", "Buyer_code"]

re_fields = re.compile(r'(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})(.{8})(.{6})(\s*.{5})(.{4})(\s*.{7})(.{7})(\s*.{4})(.{4})(\s*.{5})(.{8})(.{7})(.{4})(.*?)(.{2})$')


with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_writer.writerow(headings)
    
    for line in f_input:
        fields = list(re_fields.match(line).groups())

        fields[3] = "{}.{}.{}".format(fields[3][:2], fields[3][2:4], fields[3][4:])
        fields[7] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[7][:-2], fields[7][-2:]))
        fields[8] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[8][:-2], fields[8][-2:]))
        fields[12] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[12][:6], fields[12][6:]))
        fields[13] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[13][:-2], fields[13][-2:]))

        csv_writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: This code is working. Will you able to find a solution to load multiple files (same structure ) at once

Comment: @hiran, please don't take me wrong, I can notice that you are new here and I should warn you how things work. SO is a community. We answer questions that not only one can learn from, but all the community. We spend our time studying to offer solutions for community. When someone asks, they should consider also the community. And the way you can do this is keeping questions organized so others with the same problem can easily find your question in the future.

Comment: So If you have a new question, follow the rules to create a new question. And, please, if is the case, inform community that this answer addresses problems like yours, marking this answer as accepted. I know, this is not as easy as hiring a service fully dedicated to your problems, but this is a way that you can help others also. :)

Comment: Though I want to vote you for the above question , I couldn't do it because I don't have 15 reputations. Any way I'll ask the question separately. Any way thanks for the reply.

Comment: Now you are almost there :)